# specify Series label and multiple yaxes's together

Tags: jqplot

is there a way to specify labels when we are using multiple y axes's

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var line1=[['11-01-11',2052], ['11-02-11',2205], ['11-03-11',1910], ['11-04-     11',2085], ['11-05-11',2261],  ['11-06-11',1714],  ['11-07-11',3123];

     var line2=[['11-01-11',2121], ['11-02-11',32323], ['11-03-11',65656], ['11-04-  11',21212], ['11-05-11',32323],  ['11-06-11',54544],  ['11-07-11',31230]];

var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1, line2], {
title:'Margin vs Date',
axes:{
    xaxis:{
        renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
    },
    yaxis:{  autoscale:true},  
      y2axis:{
          autoscale:true, 
          tickOptions:{showGridline:false}
      }

},
series:[{lineWidth:4}, {yaxis:'y2axis'}]

  });
  });
  </script>
```

but when i try to specify labels for these two series  none of the labels are shown,

```
  series:[{label: 'hello' }, {label: 'Hi'},{lineWidth:4}, {yaxis:'y2axis'}]
```

is there a way to get it done?

[image: grap With two y axe's]

Answer (score 1):

In my answer, I'm assuming you are referring to axes labels, and not a table legend.

First, for the sake of thoroughness.  Your dates are translating to 1911, which I doubt is the intention.  (If you do `new Date("11-03-11")` js translates that as 1911).

Also, make sure you enablePlugins

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
```

All that said, axes labels are defined on the actual axes properties, not the series properties. So, using your code as an example, the following works for me:

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var line1=[['11-01-2011',2052], ['11-02-2011',2205], ['11-03-2011',1910], ['11-04-2011',2085], ['11-05-2011',2261],  ['11-06-2011',1714],  ['11-07-2011',3123]];
    var line2=[['11-01-2011',2121], ['11-02-2011',32323], ['11-03-2011',65656], ['11-04-  11',21212], ['11-05-2011',32323],  ['11-06-2011',54544],  ['11-07-2011',31230]];

    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1, line2], {
      title:'Margin vs Date',
      axes:{
          xaxis:{
              renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer            
          },
          yaxis:{  
            autoscale:true,
            label: "hello"
          },  
          y2axis:{
            autoscale:true, 
            tickOptions:{showGridline:false},
            label: "Hi"
          }

      },
      series:[{lineWidth:4}, {yaxis:'y2axis'}]
    });
  });
</script>
```

If you then wanted to take it further, and rotate the labels, you'll want to look into using the canvasTextRenderer and canvasAxisLabelRenderer plugins.